# Kafka consumer always giving a java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to execute the below command:

```
./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list 101.10.51.1:9092,101.10.51.4:9092 --topic namespace_deep_archive_d_billing_transaction --time -2
```

And the program is always getting the following error:

```
[2018-08-23 12:36:58,604] WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 0 for topics [Set(namespace_deep_archive_d_billing_transaction)] from broker [BrokerEndPoint(0,101.10.51.1,9092)] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:124)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:82)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:81)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:126)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:63)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:99)
        at kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell$.main(GetOffsetShell.scala:98)
        at kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell.main(GetOffsetShell.scala)
[2018-08-23 12:36:59,616] WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 0 for topics [Set(namespace_deep_archive_d_billing_transaction)] from broker [BrokerEndPoint(1,101.10.51.4,9092)] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
```

I am running the `getOffset` from a different server. But, this server can telnet to the kafka brokers.

If anyone faced this issue, how did you resolve it?

Comment: Could you please share the full Stack error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the GetOffsetShell and back-traced the problem to missing entry in `/etc/hosts` file.

This is the snippet from GetOffsetShell.scala

```
   val url = new URI(options.valueOf(urlOpt))
    val topic = options.valueOf(topicOpt)
    val partition = options.valueOf(partitionOpt).intValue
    var time = options.valueOf(timeOpt).longValue
    val nOffsets = options.valueOf(nOffsetsOpt).intValue
    val consumer = new SimpleConsumer(url.getHost, url.getPort, 10000, 100000)
```

Even though I pass IP address of the brokers, they get resolved into their corresponding hostnames.
The consumer code does a lookup on `/etc/hosts` and cant find a mapping between hostname and IP address,exception is raised.

On adding server-name and IP in /etc/hosts , the code is now able to get offsets and consume records from the kafka brokers.

Reference: 
https://github.com/kafka-dev/kafka/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/GetOffsetShell.scala
https://github.com/kafka-dev/kafka/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/kafka/consumer/SimpleConsumer.scala
https://github.com/spujadas/elk-docker/issues/54

Comment: Yes, this works. I encountered the same problem and added hostname and IP address in /etc/hosts, the problem solved. Thank you very much.